# Функция, которая принимает два списка и возвращает словарь для каждой пары значений

Tags: python

Есть два списка:

```
list_1 = ['Elliot', 'Spencer', 'John']
list_2 = ['01/01/2000', '09/10/1999', '21/12/1990']
```

Необходимо чтобы функция возвращала для каждой пары значений словарь в виде:

```
my_dict = {'name': ..., 'date': ...}
```

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, исходя из ваших входных данных, что вы ожидаете получить на выходе.

Comment: словарь для каждой пары значений (т.е. 3 словаря) Такого типа {'name': 'Elliot', 'date': '01/01/2000'}

Comment: def create_authors_dicts(names: list, dates: list): for name, date in zip(names, dates): authors_dict = dict(name=name, date=date) return authors_dict Это будет работать корректно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> [{'name': name, 'date': date} for name, date in zip(['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2', '3'])]
[{'name': 'A', 'date': '1'}, {'name': 'B', 'date': '2'}, {'name': 'C', 'date': '3'}]
```

Comment: def create_authors_dicts(names: list, dates: list):
    for name, date in zip(names, dates):
        authors_dict = dict(name=name, date=date)
        return authors_dict                        Это будет работать корректно?

Answer (score 1):

```
def x_dict(list1, list2):
    a = {}
    for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
        a.update(dict([(x, y)]))
    return a


print(x_dict(['Elliot', 'Spencer', 'John'], ['01/01/2000', '09/10/1999', '21/12/1990']))

>>> {'Elliot': '01/01/2000', 'Spencer': '09/10/1999', 'John': '21/12/1990'}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Немного не так. Должно вернуть 3 разных словаря в формате {'name': 'Elliot', 'date': '01/01/2000'}